# Space station gains enough mass to lose orbit?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, mass, orbital-motion

I.S.S is constantly being improved (add-ons).

Will the space station need to be moved to a higher orbit at some point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each bit of additional mass brought to the ISS, be it an astronaut, cosmonaut, touristonaut, consumables, scientific instruments, new modules, etc, etc, must be brought to the same orbit in order to be brought aboard. As long as the total mass of the ISS remains negligible compared to the Earths mass that added mass does not change the orbit or affect its stability.

Comment: But the increase in size causes more atmospheric drag. The ISS has to be boosted periodically to maintain its orbit.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Sure. But on the flip side, mass brought inboard (i.e. not increasing the cross-section) lowers the effect of the drag. You win some you lose some.